# How many points are need for Pose Estimation with DLT?

Tags: image, opencv, camera, estimation

I'm wondering how many 2D <-> 3D Point correspondences are needed for a pose estimation of a camera in computer vision with Direct Linear Transformation Algorithm and why?

In pose estimation the 3x4 matrix that is searched is [R | T] which has 12 unknown parameters. In DLT every point correspondence gives 2 linear undependent equations, so I assume, one would need 6 correspondences for solving the equations.

In `openCV` implementation of `solvePnp` there are only 4 points needed and I can't figure out why.

It would really help if someone could explain how much correspondences are needed for a pose estimation and why. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are only six parameters in exterior orientation (or pose), three for orientation and three for the position. Basically we need only three points to estimate the pose of the camera (as you stated each point gives two constraints) however it is not going to give you a unique solution but you're sure you have a finite number of solutions.

So with at least four points you get a unique solution. This is a non linear problem which needs an iterative approach.

If you use the matrix with 12 unknowns then you can solve the problem linearly and you can find the closest rotation matrix which does not have to be orthogonal.

**Edit**

In case you're using 12 unknowns, as I said, you get just an approximation of the pose = 6 parameters. So it is another step after DFT solution.

In opencv function, I don't see where they're using DFT, check this [link](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#bool%20solvePnP(InputArray%20objectPoints,%20InputArray%20imagePoints,%20InputArray%20cameraMatrix,%20InputArray%20distCoeffs,%20OutputArray%20rvec,%20OutputArray%20tvec,%20bool%20useExtrinsicGuess,%20int%20flags))

Method for solving a PnP problem:

`CV_ITERATIVE` Iterative method is based on Levenberg-Marquardt optimization. In this case the function finds such a pose that minimizes reprojection error, that is the sum of squared distances between the observed projections imagePoints and the projected (using projectPoints() ) objectPoints .

`CV_P3P` Method is based on the paper of X.S. Gao, X.-R. Hou, J. Tang, H.-F. Chang “Complete Solution Classification for the Perspective-Three-Point Problem”. In this case the function requires exactly four object and image points.

`CV_EPNP` Method has been introduced by F.Moreno-Noguer, V.Lepetit and P.Fua in the paper “EPnP: Efficient Perspective-n-Point Camera Pose Estimation”.

**EDIT**

I read the implementation and you're right, they start with [DFT](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/f824db4803855ca30bf782f8bb37ca39051f319f/modules/calib3d/src/calibration.cpp) just to initialize the 6 parameters of the camera and then they use [CvLevMarq Class](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/f824db4803855ca30bf782f8bb37ca39051f319f/modules/calib3d/src/calibration.cpp#L1099) to minimize the error reprojection.

Comment: Thank you! Does that mean if I want to solve it linearly with the 12 unknows I need 6 points and otherwise (non-linear solution) only 4 points?
If that's the case then I don't understand how openCV solves it linearly (with DLT) with only 4 points.

Comment: Hi, yes they use it if there is no initial extrinsic guess given. And it works with 4 points as it's written in the implementation. So I don't quite understand how they can solve the 12 unknowns with 4 points (= 8 constraints), as I would expect you need 6 points for using the DLT. Are there any extra constraints that I didn't consider?

Comment: @DeepC1 DFT with the approximation added to it, it gives an inaccurate result so opencv doesn't rely on that algorithm to compute the pose but it gives a good initialization for PnP algorithm and others

Answer (score 0):

when we only have 4 known 3D-2D correspondences, that is, the number of homogeneous linear equations (8) is less than the number of unknown parameters (12), there will be countless non-zero solutions. We only provide one possible or feasible solution among them to the iterative solver as an initial estimation. This solution can be selected based on some constraints like ||x||=1, etc.
Does it make sense?